# Unable to Start a Node on Jenkins Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automation, jenkins-plugins, selenium-grid

I am trying to get Selenium Grid up and running using Jenkins as the hub, and another Slave PC's as the nodes.  I have installed the Selenium Plugin and created a configuration for the main node to match my slave PCs.  Those Slave PC's are displayed under the nodes matching configurations, but when I click on the Start action, nothing happens.  I looked in the log file, and it says Starting Selenium nodes on *.  And the next line is just the spinning wheel with no more data below.  And under Running Configurations, I do not see anything.  What else do I need to do to get the nodes connected to Selenium?
enter image description here[image: Hub Configuration][image: node configuration page 1][image: node configuration page 2][image: Specific Node Home][image: Specific Node Config][image: Specific Node Log]

Comment: The current information you shared is not sufficient to help troubleshoot. Is there anything you can think of additional context, that you could perhaps add here ? Maybe share screenshots of how your entire setup looks like including the configurations ? You could also share the Grid plugin version that you are working with.

Comment: Post more details about your configurations and the Jenkins scripts

Comment: I have added screenshots of my configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to start Jenkins as a Service on the Salve Machines.